# What does the forward slash mean set notation mean?

Tags: notation

I have an equation that looks like this:

$L(\hat{x}_i, y_i, S) =\begin{cases}
  \hat{x}_i -  y_i & \text{if $i \in S1$} \\
                \infty & \text{if $i \in S / \{S2,S3\}$}
  \end{cases}$

What does this mean

$i \in S / \{S2,S3\}$

Comment: Maybe is \setminus ($\setminus$) i.e. set difference.

Comment: If we have that $S_1, S_2, S_3 \in S$, it is likely so.

Comment: Usually a set difference will be denoted by a backslash but this was fairly unambiguously intended to mean a set difference by whoever wrote it, I believe. (Well, as @MauroALLEGRANZA notes, we'd have to know a little more about $S$ to be sure, but I'd bet on it.)